# Reloading webpage Issue - web view not passing through functions

Tags: swift, xcode, web, webview

Trying to have a static webpage refresh every 60 seconds; however I am getting an error in the refresh function: " Cannot find 'webview' in scope". Was wondering if someone would be able to assist.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.refresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
        func CGRectMake(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGRect
        {
            return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        }
        let webViewClass : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("UIWebView")!
        let webViewObject : NSObject.Type = webViewClass as! NSObject.Type
        let webview: AnyObject = webViewObject.init()
        let url = NSURL(string: "XXXXXXX")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        let uiview = webview as! UIView
        uiview.frame = CGRectMake(-90, -60, 2080, 1200)
        view.addSubview(uiview)
    }
    
    @objc func refresh()
    {
        webview.reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the guy named 'webview' defined?

Comment: line 14: "let webview: AnyObject = webViewObject.init()"

the value can't be passed from the ViewDidLoad to refresh function.

Comment: What makes you think your app can access that variable from the refresh guy when it's declared under `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I understand that, that's why I'm needing some assistance in being able to pass the variable to the other function (or finding another way to refresh the webpage every 60 seconds)

Comment: Take the web guy out of `viewDidLoad` and declare it right below the class name  or wherever with `var`.

Comment: Have attempted that but unfortunately every line spits up an error as they state:
- Cannot use instance member 'webViewClass' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
- Cannot use instance member 'webViewObject' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
- Cannot use instance member 'url' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
etc.